# Android: strange scaling issue on button with topDrawable

Tags: android, image, button, image-scaling

In my app I'm building a button bar as part of my UI with the following XML (note that this is not the entire layout, just the button bar part of it):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnTopObjects"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/media_guide_object"
        android:text="@string/media_screen_top_objects"
        android:background="@drawable/media_guide_button"
        android:textSize="9dp"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnTrails"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/media_guide_trail"
        android:text="@string/media_screen_trails"
        android:background="@drawable/media_guide_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="9dp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnEvents"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/media_guide_event"
        android:text="@string/media_screen_events"
        android:background="@drawable/media_guide_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="9dp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnVenueInfo"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/media_guide_venue"
        android:text="@string/media_screen_venue_info"
        android:background="@drawable/media_guide_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="9dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This produces a reasonably correct results when I test it on 320x480 screen.  The button bar looks like this, which is exactly what I want:

[image]

However on a device with 480x800 resolution screen, the same button bar looks like this:

[image]

What's really bizzarre is how the four buttons are displayed.  The first three images are scaled down while the last one is displayed full-size.

All 4 images are created the same way in the same graphics program.  They all are 31x31 pixels 72dpi.  I don't have a problem if they all scale down according to the device pixel density, but I want the 4 images to be the same size!  How can I achieve this?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: One possible cause is that the image for 'venue info' is not present in the drawable-hdpi folder and so the image from drawable or drawable-mdpi is being scaled up (or vice versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tracked down the problem to the following.

Once the view is created from XML, then in the code under some conditions I load the image into a Bitmap and perform some operations on it before setting this Bitmap as the BitmapDrawable into the button using `setCompoundDrawable` method.

When the XML is first loaded and set into the view, all four images are displayed like the last button (large image).  When I load the bitmap, perform some transformation on it and set it as the drawable to the button - that's when it's scaled down based on the screen density of the device.  It so happened that the first three buttons had the drawable adjusted and the last one didn't need to.

I amended the code to always load the bitmaps and then set the drawables onto the buttons - for all buttons, regardless of whether they need to be adjusted or not.  This way all four buttons are not displayed with the same size images (scaled based on screen density - but all the same size).